# Seam & JSF - misunderstanding <h:inputHidden />?

Tags: java, html, jsf, seam, hidden-field

I've written an e-commerce web application using Seam 2.2, JPA, and JSF that, of course, contains product search functionality.  To accomplish this, I've created a class called `SearchForm` that contains the various parameters used for searching (start index, maximum number of results, 'and' terms, 'or' terms, etc.)  I've also got a web action -- `ProductSearchAction` -- that uses the `SearchForm` object to pull the entries from the database.  It looks something like this:

```
@Name("searchForm")
@AutoCreate
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class SearchForm {

   private int startIndex = 0;

   private int maxResults = 20;

   ...

}


@Name("productSearchAction")
@AutoCreate
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class ProductSearchAction {

   @In
   private SearchForm searchForm = null;

   @Out
   private List<Products> products = null;

   ...

   public void searchProducts() {
      ...
   }

   ...

}
```

In my JSF, I display the list of products enclosed within an `<h:form />`, with 2 `<h:commandLink />` links for paging forward and backward through the results.  Since I don't create a conversation for each search, I'm trying to pass state to the `ProductSearchAction` and `SearchForm` objects through the use of `<h:inputHidden />` hidden fields.  I've got fields like this in my page:

```
<h:form>
   ...

   <h:inputHidden value="#{searchForm.maxResults}" />
   <h:inputHidden value="#{searchForm.startIndex}" />
   <h:inputHidden value="#{searchForm.andTerms}" />

   ...

   <h:commandLink action="next" value="Next" />
   <h:commandLink action="previous" value="Previous" />
</h:form>
```

My understanding of `<h:inputHidden />` is that it will populate the appropriate values within `SearchForm`, which will then be made available to `ProductSearchAction.searchProducts()`.  When I view the HTML source I see the hidden parameters being set within the HTML.  However, when I click "next" or "previous" which take me to the `searchProducts()` action none of the values are set.

Am I misunderstanding how `<h:inputHidden />` works?  What do I need to do to pass these values to my search action?  Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?  Is it a Seam Scope issue?  I'd REALLY appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: It sounds like your understanding of JSF and h:inputHidden is correct.  To troubleshoot, try adding h:outputText to your page with the same values.  Also try h:outputText value="#{searchForm}" to see whether searchForm is being exposed to your JSF view at all - perhaps there's something wrong in the Seam/JSF wiring.

Comment: I definitely see the hidden input values being written when I do a view source, so I know that they're at least in place within the HTML itself.  However, when I click the "next" or "previous" links which take me to searchProducts() I don't see those values in my searchForm object.

Comment: Please show your navigation configs/logic --  how "next" leads to searchProducts()

Comment: In general, <h:inputHidden /> will render the value present in previous request and put that values back in the same bean on post-back. @Scope(CONVERSATION) gives you additional advantage of preserving the bean-values across redirects. BTW, the behavior of <inputHidden /> JSF-wise is very similar to <inputText />, so use <inputText /> during development/debugging, and convert them to <inputHidden /> after everything works as expected. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment it sounds like you are using h:inputHidden correctly, and that the problem must lie in the JSF bean scoping.

The beans are behaving as if they are request scope.  When you fire of a h:commandLink, the page re-renders and posts the hidden inputs back, and then those posted values are not available after the navigation result ("next" or "prev") forwards to another page.

In all likelihood the @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION) is not behaving as you expect it to.  I am not a Seam expert, but from a quick scan of the documentation it looks like Seam treats each individual HTTP request as a "conversation" unless otherwise indicated.  So that would explain why the values reset when you click the commandLink.  You probably need to demarcate a *long-running conversation* with the @Begin/@End annotations.

http://seamframework.org/Community/ConversationExample